# Slack button response back to dialogflow to trigger followup intent fullfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack, slack-api

In my case I am creating a slack chat bot using dialogflow. On saying "Hi" to the bot, it responds with 3 buttons out of which user has to chose. Based on the choice made the subsequent intent has to be triggered.

I am able to create buttons in slack chat bot but cant able to get the selection back to dialogflow and trigger the desired intent.

Sample code:

```
function welcome (agent) {
    agent.add( new Payload(agent.SLACK, {
   "text":'Welcome ',
    "attachments": [
      {
        "text": "Please choose any of the following options",
        "actions": [
          {`enter code here`
            "name": "General Enquiries",
            "type": "button",
            "text": "General Enquiries",
            "value": "General Enquiries"
          },
          {
            "name": "Account Related Queries",
            "type": "button",
            "text": "Account Related Queries",
            "value": "Account Related Queries"
          },
          {
            "name": "Complaints",
            "type": "button",
            "text": "Complaints",
            "value": "Complaints"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

    }) );

  }

  function accountQueries (agent){
    agent.add('Hi buddy');
  }

  function Complaints (agent){
    agent.add('Hi teddy');
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set(WELCOME_INTENT, welcome);
  intentMap.set(ACCOUNT_RELATED_QUERIES, accountQueries);
  intentMap.set(COMPLAINTS, Complaints);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

Comment: are you getting any error?